# Which control can be used to represent an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I am trying to build an interface that uses some visual element that represents an instance of a particular class.  When you click on this element, I would like that objects particular data values to be displayed on the side.  Which would be the best control to use and how would I associate this control with a particular instance of some class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`PropertyGrid`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home) in extended WPF toolkit.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little on PropertyGrid?  I understand it's a downloadable extended control that links information from an object to a "display chart".  But, using VS 2012 Express, how can I download this control and would it be easier to link objects by method of a page that accepts an object as a parameter and populates the information on the page based that way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into a `PropertyGrid`? e.g.

```
propertyGrid.SelectedObject = yourObject;
```